# Editable Form in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, forms, uitableview

I wish to build a form (posting a job add) with 3 fields: company name, job title and job description.

I have never done something so elaborate and so I would like some input in the following areas:

- Design: do I use a table view with multiple cell types or something else?
- Edition: should each cell (in case we pick a table view) lead to another view controller that I can edit or not?

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Comment: Check out how [someone else did it](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka), and try to do something similar, or just use their pod.

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately, so far I havent found a satisfactory tutorial or even project to use. but thank you for the advice. maybe I shall look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your UI, whether you want to use tableview or just textfields or something else.

If you want to display multiple ads one below other on the same screen, tableview is a good option. But, if only one ad is required per screen, then textfields will also do.

tableview has ios supplied delegates to take care of the data source and for user response. These delegates are implemented in a single viewcontroller.